# Webscrape interactive chart in Python using beautiful soup with loops

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, charts, beautifulsoup

The below code provide information from all the numeric tags in the page. Can I use a filter to extract once for each region

For example :  https://opensignal.com/reports/2019/04/uk/mobile-network-experience , I am interested in numbers only under the regional analysis tab and for all regions.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html=requests.get("https://opensignal.com/reports/2019/04/uk/mobile-network-experience").text
soup=BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')
items=soup.find_all('div',class_='c-ru-graph__rect')


for item in items:
    provider=item.find('span', class_='c-ru-graph__label').text
    prodvalue=item.find_next_sibling('span').find('span', class_='c-ru-graph__number').text
    print(provider + " : " + prodvalue)
```

I want a table or df as below 
Easter Region

```
                       o2      Vodaphone   3    EE
4G Availability        82      76.9        73.0   89.2
Upload Speed Experience 5.6    5.9         6.8    9.5
```

Any pointers that can help in getting the result ?

Comment: Where is your problem?

Comment: @Wonka , The problem is the structure of what is returned by the function. It greps every numeric information and not by region or the KPI's like 4G availability , Upload experience etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I would do it for all regions. Requires bs4 4.7.1. AFAICS you have to assume consistent ordering of companies.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

r = requests.get("https://opensignal.com/reports/2019/04/uk/mobile-network-experience")
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content,'lxml') #'html.parser' if lxml not installed
metrics = ['4g-availability', 'video-experience', 'download-speed' , 'upload-speed', 'latency']
headers = ['02', 'Vodaphone', '3', 'EE']
results = []

for region in soup.select('.s-regional-analysis__region'):
    for metric in metrics:
        providers = [item.text for item in region.select('.c-ru-chart:has([data-metric="' + metric + '"]) .c-ru-graph__number')]
        row = {headers[i] : providers[i] for i in range(len(providers))}
        row['data-metric'] = metric
        row['region'] = region['id'] 
        results.append(row)

df = pd.DataFrame(results, columns = ['region', 'data-metric', '02','Vodaphone', '3', 'EE'] )
print(df)
```

---

**Sample output:**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Assuming fixed the order of companies (it is, indeed), you can simply reduce the content to examine to only those div's containing the information you need.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = requests.get("https://opensignal.com/reports/2019/04/uk/mobile-network-experience").text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')

res = soup.find_all('div', {'id':'eastern'})

aval = res[0].find_all('div', {'data-chart-name':'4g-availability'})
avalname = aval[0].find('span', {'class':'js-metric-name'}).text

upload = res[0].find_all('div', {'data-chart-name':'upload-speed'})
uploadname = upload[0].find('span', {'class':'js-metric-name'}).text

companies = [i.text for i in aval[0].find_all('span', class_='c-ru-graph__label')]

row1 = [i.text for i in aval[0].find_all('span', class_='c-ru-graph__number')]
row2 = [i.text for i in upload[0].find_all('span', class_='c-ru-graph__number')]

import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({avalname:row1,
                   uploadname:row2})


df.index = companies

df = df.T
```

**output**

```
                          O2    Vodafone      3      EE
4G Availability         82.0        76.9   73.0    89.2
Upload Speed Experience  5.6         5.9    6.8     9.5
```

Comment: this helps but the below is automated for collecting for all regions,Thank you